# Concatenating columns with like row names

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a function to look for columns of a certain name and then concatenate them together, for example:

```
ID Code1 Code2 Code3
1  1,2   4,5   6,7
```

into

```
ID Codes
1  1,2,4,5,6,7
```

The number of "code" columns can change so I need some way to put it into a loop that looks for those columns.  I tried doing something like this, but it doesnt seem to give the right thing in the end.  Could it be because i loaded the data.table package?:

```
codeCols = which(grepl('Code', names(df), ignore.case = TRUE))
df$Codes <- paste0(merged.data.frame[, codeCols],collapse = ",")
```

Comment: If you are working with a data.table, then your second line is not correct.

Comment: damn any ideas of what would do that?would it make sense to use something like sqldf to do it like a sql query?

Comment: I'm not sure of your data structure, because you only presented one line, but you may be able to accomplish what you want by adding with=True inside your `[]`: as `paste0(merged.data.frame[, codeCols, with=TRUE],collapse = ",")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `data.table`, we can try the `Reduce`:

```
library(data.table)
cols = grep('Code', names(df), ignore.case = TRUE, value = T)

setDT(df)[, .(Codes = Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep = ","), .SD)), 
            by = list(ID), .SDcols = cols]
   ID       Codes
1:  1 1,2,4,5,6,7
```

In `data.frame`:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=","), df[, cols])
[1] "1,2,4,5,6,7"
```

Or

```
dt <- setDT(df)
Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=","), dt[, cols, with=F])
[1] "1,2,4,5,6,7"
```

**Update**:
If the `ID` column is unique for each row, you can eliminate the use of Reduce function as follows:

```
setDT(df)[, .(Codes = paste0(unlist(.SD), collapse = ",")), by = list(ID), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(df[-1], 1,  FUN = paste, collapse=",")
#[1] "1,2,4,5,6,7"
```